# How get & scroll down any x element on the list

Tags: python, selenium, loops, scroll

I try to get with selenium, a few instagram's users on following list depending scrolling :

[image]

So i need a loop able to scraping any 7 users scrolling down

It important i have control over "number i put" (number of users I want) i don't want necessarily until end of scrolling because if the profile who i want to **scrape**, have lot of following and finally i want then 100 users it will be useless...

My code :

```
following = []

elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//div[@class='PZuss']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa ']")
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"

# Generate a list where to put the followers name

actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)

for i in range(7): # 7 this is maximum number users that we can see in modal
    val = elems[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
    following.append(url+val)
    print(following)
    sleep(1)
    actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
            
    print(following)
```

...but i have 2 problem :

1. I can't control scrolling with `actionChain.key_down`, i already try with `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -100)")` it doesn't work with instagram modal
2. It doesn't return me what i want have :
   [image]

Thanks

Comment: the 2nd problem can be fixed by un-indenting `print(following)` so it's not printing in every loop iteration.  It needs to be outside of the loop so it only prints one list, with all URL's, at the end

Comment: regarding problem 1, you may be targeting the wrong window to scroll. You might have to switch windows for the modal

Comment: @JD2775 yeah but if i do this, i can't see all URL on the list, and if i put the `print` to outside it working only for the first element

Comment: @c-Peck i try this with the class name of modal `browser.execute_script("pbNvD  fPMEg      HYpXt.scrollTo(0, -100)")` ...but it doesen't work